# AWS: VPC is not showing up in "Create Auto Scaling Group" wizard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-ecs

I m trying to create Auto Scaling Group.

When I go to select "Network" option in the 1st screen of "Create Auto Scaling Group" wizard, VPC that I created is not coming as an option to select.

Comment: Are you in the same region where your VPC is?

Comment: Yup! I m trying to create autoscaling group in the same region where I have created VPC.

Comment: This is kind of a pain, but you could try making a CloudFormation template that sets this up and see if it works. If it doesn't work, it may at least give you a helpful error that can point you in the right direction.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your VPC will not show up if it does not have any associated subnets.

Answer (score 0):

> 1st screen of "Create Auto Scaling Group" wizard

only listed **ClassicLink-Enabled** VPC. The normal vpc you have created, you will choose when you create AutoScalingGroup base on this AutuScalingConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

When I go and select "Network" option in the 1st screen of "Create Auto Scaling Group" wizard, VPC that I created is not coming as an option to select.

This is browser issue for me(in Google Chrome), but when i opened in IE, i was able to see all the VPCs.
Hope this helps someone.